# Do UTM properties in URL work without gtag.js?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, utm-tracking

Maybe it's a silly question but couldn't find an answer for it other than for the opposite question.

If I have my website already connected with Google Analytics, do I still need to add `gtag.js` in order for UTM properties in an URL to be tracked?

I'm not really sure how would Google be able to track it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Google Analytics snippet in all pages. So, in this case if UTM parameter are in the URL it will be tracked automatically.